# Where does Chrome store redirects?

Tags: google-chrome

I am dealing with a server that is being redirected.

For example when I enter http://195.20.241.96/, Chrome redirects me to http://somedomain.xyz

Now I have changed this redirect.
When I open a new Incognito tab in Chrome, it stays at http://195.20.241.96/.
However, in the non-Incognito tab, it still redirects to http://somedomain.xyz

I would like to remove this redirection.

Where do Chrome stores this redirection?

Thank you!

Comment: It must be stored in your browser's cache.

Comment: Ok, but where exactely?

Comment: Google Chrome's browser cache is often, but not always in your %APPDATA%/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Cache. However this differs for OS's, versions of Chrome etc, (And it's not always clear which part of the cache is the redirect you're looking for) so the only reliable way to get rid of the redirect is to clear your entire cache. For testing purposes you may want to consider 302 (=non-permanent) redirects in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google Chrome [cache permanent redirects](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2008/12/google-chrome-caches-301-redirects.html). To clear them, go to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`. Clearing the **cached images and files** will do.

It's unclear that where the Chrome stores the redirects.

Comment: The situation is [similar for Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/454036/11510): 1) You can reliably clear the domain-specific storage and with this also the cached HTTP redirections. 2) But there is no method to delete only the cached HTTP redirections of a particular domain. 3) And there are no tools to inspect/manipulate the cached HTTP redirections. 4) And I found no traces of them getting persisted to disk at all. They seem to live solely in RAM.